# How do you use SKTextureFilteringNearest with SKTextureAtlas

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I seem to be having a problem using SKTextureAtlas and nearest neighbor filtering for textures. When I used the nearest neighbor filtering without SKTextureAtlas it works fine, but everything is just changed to linear filtering when I use an SKTextureAtlas.

Code and Result Without SKTextureAtlas:

```
SKTexture* texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"grass"];
texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKSpriteNode* node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture size:CGSizeMake(512,512)];
```

*Should Produce Nearest Neighbor Filtering & Does*
[image]

Code and Result With SKTextureAtlas:

```
SKTextureAtlas* atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"myAtlas"];
SKTexture* texture = [atlas textureNamed:@"grass"];
texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKSpriteNode* node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture size:CGSizeMake(512,512)];
```

*Should Produce Nearest Neighbor Filtering & **DOES NOT***
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try spriteNodeWithTexture: without specifying size, does that make a difference? For me nearest filter with atlas textures works, I haven't tried changing the sprite rect on init though. You can still scale the sprite after creating it via xScale/yScale.

Comment: Alright I tried that and I get the same result :(

Comment: I couldn't get your way working but isntead of setting the size in the init, i set the size afterwards is `[node setSize:];` and it worked

Comment: I am using a 64x64 texture and I have an object called GrassNode which inherits from SKSpriteNode, which I originally had the size and scale code which failed. Now when I declare the GrassNode in the scene and use [grass setSize:CGSizeMake(1,1)]; it still fails. Can you describe to me your layout and maybe I can figure it out.

Comment: If it comes out that there is not actual solution to my problem, I'll probably just upscale my textures so they remain sharp at higher resolutions.

Answer (score 4):

I have been struggling with exactly the same problem.

It seems that when you set the filtering mode for a SKTexture coming from an SKTextureAtlas it sets the filtering mode for everything coming out of that atlas.

I ended up solving it by making two SKTextureAtlas's (AtlasLinear and AtlasNearest). One is for my normal artwork the other is for pixelart. This works as a charm.

However with very small atlasses I sometimes get weird small pixel errors. If this pops up for you, it actually helps to add some big white block png's to your pixel art atlas.

Good luck.

Comment: It's not two different instantiations of the same texture atlas. It's actually two physically different folders (pixelArt.atlas and normalTextures.atlas). When I load them in I set the filtering mode on them and it affects all the sprites with textures from them.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a bizarre problem.  It seems to me that there is a missing API: `[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:atlasName withFilteringMode:filteringMode]`

In lieu of such an API for the time being, I use the following method:

```
-(SKTextureAtlas *) textureAtlasWithName:(NSString *)atlasName filteringMode:(SKTextureFilteringMode)filteringMode {

    SKTextureAtlas * result = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:atlasName];

    NSArray * textureNames = [result textureNames];

    if ([textureNames count] > 0) {
        SKTexture * aTexture = [result textureNamed:[textureNames lastObject]];
        [aTexture setFilteringMode:filteringMode];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"WARNING: couldn't find any textures in the atlas %@; filtering mode set likely failed.", result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem in my program. What I have found out is that if a texture atlas is instantiated more than once, even if all texture loads from the atlases are set to SKTextureFilteringNearest, the textures are rendered with the linear filtering. What I ended up doing is provide my atlas through a singleton and made sure all textures load with filtering set to SKTextureFilteringNearest and it worked perfectly.